# how to order arraylist of objects by object variable string

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

obj contains
name
price
date

How do I order by date, name or price with ascending and descendeding functionalities?

thank you for your time

Comment: what if it's an ArrayList

Comment: An ArrayList is a type of List, so that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some method to do that.

1, Streams:

```
 list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getPrice))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

For the reversing order:

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getName).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

2, `Comparator`

`list.sort(comparator)` or `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`

```
Comparator<MyObj> priceComparator=new Comparator<MyObj>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(MyObj o1, MyObj o2) {
    //Note that compareTo only available if you implement comparable
    //If not, return values I describe later
    //Or use Comparator.comparing(field/keyExtractor)
    return o1.getPrice().compareTo(o2.getPrice());
  }
})
```

You can create implementation to any field. You can implement logic here to combine fields etc.

3, Implement `Comparable` interface in the Data object.

```
public class MyObj implements Comparable<MyObj> {

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyObj o) {
    return price.compareTo(o.getPrice());
  }

 [...]
}
```

`Comparator` is much more flexible then `Comparable`, because you can select the behaviour runetime.
If you need custom logic, you can write it in the compare method.

You can return with:

```
 0 if equals
 1 if left is greater
-1 if right is greater
```

For example in a custom Comparator:

```
 public int compare(MyObj o1, MyObj o2) {
    int result=0;
    if(o1.price>o2.price) result=1;
    [...]
    return result;
  }
```